Issue with exporting async function to other javascript file
I'm new to JavaScript async/await and can't seem to understand why my browser wouldn't display anything when I use async and await with JS modules
pokeUtils.js
export async function fetchPokemon(){
    try{
        const pokeName = document.getElementById("pokemonName").value.toLowerCase();
        
        if (!pokeName) { 
            throw new Error("Please enter a Pokemon name!");
        }
        
        const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeName}`);

        if(!response.ok || response.status === 404){
            throw new Error("Could not fetch Pokemon! - " + response.status)
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error)
    }
}


main.js
import { fetchPokemon } from "./pokeUtils";

document.getElementById("fetchButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
    try {
        const data = await fetchPokemon();
        const pokemonSprite = data.sprites.front_default;
        const imgElement = document.getElementById("pokemonImg");
        imgElement.src = pokemonSprite;
        imgElement.style.display = "block";
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fetch a Pokemon!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <input type="text" id="pokemonName" placeholder="Enter Pokemon Name?">
    <button id="fetchButton">Fetch Pokemon!</button>
    <img src="" alt="Pokemon Sprite" id="pokemonImg" style="display: none;"> 

    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Expecting to see the Pokemon Sprite to be displayed on the front end but it doesn't display anything and the console is blank

in main.js
change the first line
import { fetchPokemon } from "./pokeUtils";

into
import { fetchPokemon } from "./pokeUtils.js";

and it will work!

@user22975319 - you said the console is blank - surely it would not be blank given the error you made!
